# To get JSON objects based on the current date

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an `JSON` file called `tasks`.it's template looks like this:

[image]

**JSON File**

```
[
  {
    "taskName": "Task - 1",
    "id": "01",
    "startDate": "2019-04-17T18:30:00Z" <==========
  },
  {
    "taskName": "Task - 2",
    "id": "02",
    "startDate": "2019-04-22T14:30:00Z"
  },
  {
    "taskName": "Task - 3",
    "id": "03",
    "startDate": "2019-04-17T12:30:00Z" <========
  },
  {
    "taskName": "Task - 4",
    "id": "04",
    "startDate": "2019-04-25T18:10:00Z"
  }
]
```

As in the JSON i have property called `startDate` based on the `startDate` I want to display the tasks, like this:

[image]

I have tried to filter based on the Date like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let task of getTaskByDate(myDate)">
    <tr>
        <td>Task Name: </td>
        <td>{{task.taskName }}</td>
    </tr>   
</div>
```

**TS**

```
  tasks: ITasks;
  myDate = new Date();

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getTasks()
      .subscribe(res => this.tasks = res);
  }


    public getTaskByDate (myDate: string): ITasks  {
    return this.tasks ? this.tasks.filter(x => x.startDate === myDate) : [];
  }
```

What's wrong with my approach?
Here is the 
**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-i6mv9t?file=src/models/app.models.ts)**

Comment: What's wrong is that a value of type Date can't possibly be === to another value of type string, since they don't even have the same type. And even if they were of the same type, new Date() returns the current time, precise up to the millisecond. The probability of that time being exactly equal to the date 2019-04-22T14:30:00Z is extremely low. You need to parse the strings as Date and check if their day is the same as the current day.

Comment: tyr converting your`x.startDate` to dateformat from string

Comment: your are comparing two dates wrongly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html you call `let task of getTaskByDate(myDate)` where `myDate = new Date();` so `public getTaskByDate (myDate: string): ITasks` would be `public getTaskByDate (myDate: Date): ITasks`

After that, matching the Date is easy.:

First method (change filter rule)
`new Date(x.startDate).toDateString() === myDate.toDateString()`

Second method:

```
public getTaskByDate (myDate: Date): ITask[]  {
      const dateString = myDate.toJSON().substr(0, 10);
      return this.tasks ? this.tasks.filter(x => x.startDate.substr(0, 10) === dateString) : [];
  }
```

Despite your problem, you should definitive change the `ITasks`interface name to `ITask` and make the AppComponent property of type `ITask[]`, because the name is a lie. It says `ITasks` defines a collection of `Tasks` instead of a single `Task`

Edit:
Changed type of myDate to `Date`. (`getTaskByDate (myDate: string): ITasks` to `getTaskByDate (myDate: Date): ITask[]` because myDate was always a `Date`)

Comment: In the `JSON` mistakely i was added `startDate: string`, Now i have changed.

Comment: Your solution works fine, But i made an mistake while posting the `JSON`. Actually `startDate` is of type `date` not `string`. If the `startDate` is of type `date` then its unable apply `substr` method for it.

Comment: Yes if `startDate` is of type `Date` then you have two `Date` objects: You should compare them `startDate.toDateString() === myDate.toDateString()`. Or: `startDate.toDateString() === dateString` and change the line `const dateString = myDate.toJSON().substr(0, 10);` to `const dateString = myDate.toDateString();` (so you would not call this method x times as it would not change)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you should be aware of:

1. The `startDate` property is of type `string`, so comparing that with a `Date` will not work; it needs to be converted to a proper `Date` object first.
2. Your `startDate` includes a time, so that needs to be taken into account as well.

Here's a solution using the [date-fns](https://date-fns.org) library (which supports tree-shaking), filtering tasks by date (ignoring time):

- Install Date-Fns with running `npm i date-fns`.
- Add these imports to your TypeScript file: `import { addDays, parse, startOfDay } from 'date-fns';`

```
public getTaskByDate (myDate: string): ITasks  {
  const date = parse(myDate);                    // parse input string
  const startOfSearch = startOfDay(date);        // start of the day
  const endOfSearch = addDays(startOfSearch, 1); // start of next day

  return this.tasks ? this.tasks.filter(x => {
    const parsedDate = parse(x.startDate);
    return parsedDate >= startOfSearch && parsedDate < endOfSearch;
  }) : [];
}
```

Here's a solution without Date-Fns, again only matching the date:

```
public getTaskByDate (myDate: string): ITasks  {
  const date = Date.parse(myDate);               // parse input string

  return this.tasks 
    ? this.tasks.filter(x => Date.parse(x.startDate).toDateString() === date.toDateString()) 
    : [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter will work with the following HTML

```
<h4>Today's Task</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let task of getTaskByDate(myDate)">
    <tr>
        <td>Task Name: </td>
        <td>{{task.taskName }}</td>
    </tr>   
    <hr>
</div>
```

If you look at the below, you will see that it does filter the objects and returns only the objects with `myDate = new Date().toDateString()`. The `toDateString()` converts the date to a string like `'Wed Apr 17 2019'` without the minutes and seconds and so on. This will compare two strings and might not be the best option but its a workaround.

```
public getTaskByDate (myDate: string): ITasks  {
    return this.tasks ? this.tasks.filter(x => new Date(x.startDate).toDateString() === myDate) : [];
}
```

I forked your Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-muxfzr